# Does hpdarm -Y suffice to stop IO on my hard drive?

Tags: debian, hard-disk, io, hdparm

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with two hard drives in my laptop. The first contains my root partition and my home partition. The second one is used for backups only.

I know that hard drives break down after a couple of years. As the second one is used for backups only, I want to make sure that no data is read/written while I'm not making backups. The `/etc/fstab` entry for this hard drive looks like this:

```
UUID=1ab2c3d4-1234-1234-1234-a1b2c3d4 /mnt/Backup btrfs defaults,comment=x-gvfs-show 0 2
```

At the moment, I use

```
hdparm -Y /dev/disk/by-uuid/1ab2c3d4-1234-1234-1234-a1b2c3d4
```

to set my hard drive to sleep. Is this enough?

Comment: Repeatedly spinning a disk up and down is also mechanical stress (even more so, because you now also introduce temperature changes). If you want data to stay safe, place it on a RAID6 in an air conditioned datacenter, and replace any failing harddisks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting a hard drive for sleeping is already done by the OS after a period of inactivity.

In fact, you really do not gain anything setting it to sleep manually; and if the OS needs or is using it, it won't have any visible effect.

If you really do not want to use it, umount it with

```
sudo umount /mnt/Backup
```

However it is essential you mount it on your backup scripts as otherwise the backup will be dumped to the mount point in the other disk.

Be aware of having/doing backups in the same equipment. If the equipment is stolen, lost or otherwise has an electrical or even kernel problem you may lose the contents of both disks.

An external case with the disk or it connected to your router at home would be far much more secure.